# Drop 0 value in decimal places

Tags: sql, decimal

I want to ask if anybody know the query to drop the 0 value in decimal..

E.g : A field name percent have these values

### Percent

770.00000000000000000000,
340.670000000000000000000,
96.00000000000000000000,
4400.56000000000000000000,
109.89000000000000000000,
109.00000000000000000000,
37.00000000000000000000,

Currently I'm using the query "select cast([Percent] as decimal(9,2)) as [Percent] from table" and will result in

### Result

770.00,
340.67,
96.00,
4400.56,
109.89,
109.00,
37.00,

I want the result this actually:->

770,
340.67,
96,
4400.56,
109.89,
109,
37,

Comment: presumably you are talking about when they are formatted for viewing/printing?

Comment: As far as I know, in decimal arithmetic the number of places after the decimal point are actually significant. Since they tell you to how many places the number is accurate. If you see 770 it can usually be any number between 769.5 and 770.5. However, for 770.00 the precision is much greater, with the number lying in the interval 769.995 to 770.005. So I'd be careful with throwing away 0 digits in seemingly meaningless places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of DECIMAL and FLOAT. Decimal first to round it down to 2 deciaml places, then float to remove unwanted 0's

e.g.

```
select cast(cast([Percent] as decimal(9,2)) AS FLOAT) as [Percent]
```

With the example of 340.69999999999999, first it round to 340.70, then it takes away the zero giving you 340.7. As with any rounding some precision will be lost.

Comment: Not correct i think : eg 

select cast(cast (0.55 as decimal(10,2)) as float) as p

yields : 0.55000000000000004

Comment: Peter, I ran that SQL in your example in Management Studio (SQL Server) and still got 0.55?

Comment: I ran it in sql query analyzer sql 2k, I try to find an example in MStudio

Comment: Intersting. I also tried it in SQL Query Analyzer 2000 and got 0.55000000000000004, but SQL Server 2005 and SQl Server 2008 both return it as 0.55

Comment: But the point is that converting to float, what you do last can always yield strange results since float is not capable to represent all decimal values correct

Answer (score 2):

This rather nasty TSQL might just do the job :

```
select 
  case 
    right(
       cast(cast([percent] as decimal(9,2)) as nvarchar(11))
    ,2)

    when '00' then cast(cast([percent] as int) as nvarchar(11)) as [percent]
    else cast(cast([percent] as decimal(9,2)) as nvarchar(11)) as [percent]

 end
from table
```

of course it is always returning a string, but that's inherent to your demands, you are looking for a representation for a value...

I think you should postpone that representation to where it makes more sense (report, datagrid?) and you have more tools (like string.format kinda tools) to do the job better.

Answer (score 0):

You could rather just cast to FLOAT.

Comment: Then you can end up with values as 340.69999999999999 however

Comment: That is true, you could end up with a FLOATING point number misrepresentation. Other than that I am not aware of any way of doing this in Sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT` function twice, once to drop `0` by converting to float and once to convert it to varchar with **style 128**

```
DECLARE @Sample AS TABLE
    (
     SomeNumber DECIMAL(26, 12)
    )

INSERT INTO @Sample
    VALUES  ( 770.00000000000000000000 )
,           ( 340.670000000000000000000 )
,           ( 96.00000000000000000000 )
,           ( 4400.56000000000000000000 )
,           ( 109.89000000000000000000 )
,           ( 109.00000000000000000000 )
,           ( 37.00000000000000000000 )


SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), CONVERT(FLOAT, SomeNumber), 128) AS NoZeros
    FROM @Sample
```