# MySQL Remove Trailing Zero

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a built-in function in MySQL the removes trailing zeros on the right?

I have samples and i want my output to be like this:

```
 1.0    ==>   1
 1.50   ==>   1.5
10.030  ==>  10.03
 0.50   ==>   0.5
 0.0    ==>   0
```

Comment: Similar questions: [Remove trailing zeros from decimal in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server), [Drop 0 value in decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831466/drop-0-value-in-decimal-places)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove trailing zeros in decimal value with changing length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968531/remove-trailing-zeros-in-decimal-value-with-changing-length)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it solves my problem using this:

```
(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM(CAST(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM setpoint)AS char)))) AS setpoint
```

example:

```
mysql> SELECT testid, designationid, test, measure,
              (TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM(CAST(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM setpoint)AS char)))) AS setpoint,
              (TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM(CAST(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM tmin)AS char)))) AS tmin,
              (TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM(CAST(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM tmax)AS char)))) AS tmax,
       FROM    tests
```

Comment: Doesn't this ultimately reinvent what MySQL's built-in string to numeric type casting does?

Comment: 30 will become 3. This is a BAD and WRONG answer and should never have been accepted!  Christopher McGowan gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

Easiest way by far, just add zero!

Examples:

```
SET 
    @yournumber1="1.0", 
    @yournumber2="1.50",
    @yournumber3="10.030",
    @yournumber4="0.50",
    @yournumber5="0.0"
;

SELECT 
    (@yournumber1+0),
    (@yournumber2+0),
    (@yournumber3+0),
    (@yournumber4+0),
    (@yournumber5+0)
;

+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| (@yournumber1+0) | (@yournumber2+0) | (@yournumber3+0) | (@yournumber4+0) | (@yournumber5+0) |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                1 |              1.5 |            10.03 |              0.5 |                0 |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the column your value comes from is DECIMAL or NUMERIC type, then cast it to string first to make sure the conversion takes place...ex:

```
SELECT (CAST(`column_name` AS CHAR)+0) FROM `table_name`;
```

For a shorter way, just use any built-in string function to do the cast:

```
SELECT TRIM(`column_name`)+0 FROM `table_name`;
```

Comment: `TRIM()+0` is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

This is my method:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM `table`.`column`)) FROM table
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in a situation where I could not modify the code nor the SQL query, but I was allowed to modify the database structure. So I changed the column format from DECIMAL to FLOAT and it solved my problem.

Comment: That could be a dangerous change. DECIMAL type is used for exact values. FLOAT type is for approximate values.